# Pausing AvAudioPlayer from another view controller returns EXC_BAD_ACCESS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, avaudioplayer, exc-bad-access

I've a page-based application where the root view controller has a button which is suposed to pause an AVAudioPlayer in the data view Controller.
I take for granted that you know how the root and data view controller work. Mine looks like [this](http://postimg.org/image/86ww2o3jp/).

When I'm pressing the button I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. But when I'm pausing from a button I have on data view controller it's working fine without the crash. I've tried:

• To add the pause code in a function and call the function

```
var dataView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DataViewController") as! DataViewController
dataView.pause()
```

dataViewController

```
func pause() {
    player.pause()
}
```

• Calling a function in dataView that calls a function that pauses the player

• Tried to call with

```
dataViewController().player.pause()
```

• Tried to call `player.prepareForPlay()` before `player.pause`

And all of them gives me the same error. Can it be because rootViewController doesn't have permission to edit `player` in dataViewController?

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
dataViewController().player.pause()
```

Creates a new instance of DataViewController. That new instance doesn't have a sound player. Don't do that. You need a way to get a pointer to your existing instance of dataViewController.

By the way, you should follow the Swift naming convention of naming classes and types starting with an upper-case letter. Thus the class name should be `DataViewController`.